# Global variable and integer not working in python(tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

The code is:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Calculator v1")

strip=Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=7)

strip.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

def button_click(number):

    current = strip.get()
    strip.delete(0, END)
    strip.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))

def button_clear():

    strip.delete(0, END)

def button_plus():

    global f_num
    first_number = strip.get()
    f_num = int(first_number)
    strip.delete(0, END)

def button_equal():

    second_number = strip.get()
    strip.delete(0, END)
    strip.insert(0, f_num + int(second_number))

button1=Button(root, text="1" ,padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))

button2=Button(root, text="2" ,padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(2))

button3=Button(root, text="3" ,padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(3))

button4=Button(root, text="4" ,padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(4))

button5=Button(root, text="5" ,padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(5))

button6=Button(root, text="6" ,padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))

button7=Button(root, text="7" ,padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))

button8=Button(root, text="8" ,padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))

button9=Button(root, text="9" ,padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))

button0=Button(root, text="0" ,padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(0))

button_equal=Button(root, text="=" ,padx=80, pady=20, command=button_equal())

button_plus=Button(root, text="+" ,padx=40, pady=20, command=button_plus())

button_clear=Button(root, text="Clear" ,padx=80, pady=20, command=button_clear)

button7.grid(row=1,column=0)

button8.grid(row=1,column=1)

button9.grid(row=1,column=2)

button4.grid(row=2,column=0)

button5.grid(row=2,column=1)

button6.grid(row=2,column=2)

button1.grid(row=3,column=0)

button2.grid(row=3,column=1)

button3.grid(row=3,column=2)

button0.grid(row=4, column=0)

button_equal.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

button_plus.grid(row=5,column=0)

button_clear.grid(row=5,column=1, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

This is a simple calculator

Comment: It Shows NameError: name f_num is not defined
if I sort it out somehow, it shows ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10...PLZ HELP ME ! everycode is exact copy from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXPyB4XeYLA

His code works while mine does not how is this possible????

Comment: ***"NameError: name f_num is not defined"***: That's corrcet, `f_num` is local to `def button_plus()`. As it stands it can not accessed in another class method. Take the tour [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) to learn about `class instance variable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with these two lines:

```
button_equal=Button(root, text="=" ,padx=80, pady=20, command=button_equal())

button_plus=Button(root, text="+" ,padx=40, pady=20, command=button_plus())
```

you have two options - either write `command=lambda: button_plus()` or `command=button_plus`

the difference to what you have is that in `command=button_plus()`, `button_plus()` will be executed immediately and the result of that is passed on as the argument  - while what you want is that the function itself is passed on as argument.  Without the brackets `button_plus` is "just" a reference that points to the function defined above.

Answer (score 0):

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple calculator")

e = Entry(root, width = 35, borderwidth = 5)
e.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = 10, pady = 10)

def button_click(number):
    #e.delete(0, END)
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))

def button_clear():
    e.delete(0, END)

def button_add():
   first_number = e.get()
   global f_num
   f_num = int(first_number)
   e.delete(0, END)

def button_equal():
    seccond_number = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, f_num + int(seccond_number))


button_1 = Button(root, text = "1", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root, text = "2", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root, text = "3", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root, text = "4", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root, text = "5", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root, text = "6", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root, text = "7", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root, text = "8", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root, text = "9", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 = Button(root, text = "0", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: button_click(0))
button_add = Button(root, text = "+", padx = 39, pady = 20, command = button_add)
button_equal = Button(root, text = "=", padx = 91, pady = 20, command = button_equal)
button_clear = Button(root, text = "Clear", padx = 79, pady = 20, command = button_clear)


button_1.grid(row =3, column =0,)
button_2.grid(row =3, column =1,)
button_3.grid(row =3, column =2,)

button_4.grid(row =2, column =0,)
button_5.grid(row =2, column =1,)
button_6.grid(row =2, column =2,)

button_7.grid(row =1, column =0,)
button_8.grid(row =1, column =1,)
button_9.grid(row =1, column =2,)

button_0.grid(row =4, column =0,)
button_clear.grid(row = 4, column = 1,  columnspan = 2)
button_add.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
button_equal.grid(row = 5, column = 1,  columnspan = 2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide explanation for your code to make it more helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable outside function with name f_num and access it inside a method first by declaring it using global keyword and then assign value to it.
Just like this:

```
f_num = 0    
def add():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0,END)
```